# How to get nodes list using xpath expression with XMLDOM

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Here is the xml file:

```
<ns2:root ns2="http://www.somewhere.com" id="45">
   <sending>
      .....
   </sending>
   <declaration>
       <summary>
          ....
       </summary>
       <content>
          <state>OK</state>
          <numbers>
              <number>12566</number>
          </numbers>
          <identification>
             <data>mydata1</data>
             <dat>mydat1</dat>
          </identification>
          <identification>
             <data>mydata2</data>
             <dat>mydat2</dat>
          </identification>
       </content>
   <declaration>
</ns2:root>
```

I charge my file and get the dom, everything is fine.
I tried to get the data nodes.

first, like this:

```
nlDataNodes := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectNodes(DBMS_XMLDOM.makeNode(dom),
'//' || rootName || '/declaration/content/identification/data';
```

I have a xml parsing error saying that this node is invalid:

```
ns2:root/declaration/content/identification/data
```

So I changed like this:

```
nlDataNodes := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectNodes(DBMS_XMLDOM.makeNode(dom),
'//root/declaration/content/identification/data';
```

No more parsing error but nlDataNodes (DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMNODELIST) is empty.

How should I get the lis of 'data' nodes ?

ty

Comment: Could you try to print `root` since you are getting error `ns2:root/declaration/content/identification/data`. I hope if you are able to get the `root` value then definitely you will get the position of your xml node and you can easily find the data you want using `xpath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Namespace delcation in your xml is wrong.Parser should raise an exception. `<ns2:root ns2="http://www.somewhere.com" id="45">` change to
`<ns2:root xmlns:ns2="http://www.somewhere.com" id="45">`

2) Function  `DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectNodes` has 3 attributes (3th is optional) . In you example you've omitted the last one.

```
DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectNodes(DBMS_XMLDOM.makeNode(dom),
'//ns2:root/declaration/content/identification/data','xmlns:ns2="http://www.somewhere.com"');
```

Or use * (`* select any element`)

```
  DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.selectNodes(DBMS_XMLDOM.makeNode(dom),
    '//*/declaration/content/identification/data');
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not be:

```
<ns2:root ns2="http://www.somewhere.com" id="45">
```

But should be:

```
<ns2:root xmlns:ns2="http://www.somewhere.com" id="45">
```

So, you could do:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE xml_t IS TABLE OF XMLTYPE;

  xml_nodes xml_t;

  xml CLOB := 
    '<ns2:root ns2="http://www.somewhere.com" id="45">
       <sending></sending>
       <declaration>
           <summary></summary>
           <content>
              <state>OK</state>
              <numbers>
                  <number>12566</number>
              </numbers>
              <identification>
                 <data>mydata1</data>
                 <dat>mydat1</dat>
              </identification>
              <identification>
                 <data>mydata2</data>
                 <dat>mydat2</dat>
              </identification>
           </content>
       <declaration>
    </ns2:root>';
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO xml_nodes
  FROM   XMLTABLE(
           XMLNAMESPACES( 'http://www.somewhere.com' AS "ns2" ),
           '//ns2:root/declaration/content/identification/data'
           PASSING XMLTYPE( REPLACE( xml, '<ns2:root ns2="', '<ns2:root xmlns:ns2="' ) )
           COLUMNS node XMLTYPE PATH '.'
         );

  FOR i IN 1 .. xml_nodes.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( xml_nodes(i).getStringVal() );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```